# Messing with convexity defects

Tags: python, opencv

currently I am working in `opencv-python` with convexity defects.
From the manual I have got the following code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('star.jpg')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 127, 255,0)
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,2,1)
cnt = contours[0]
hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt,returnPoints = False)
defects = cv2.convexityDefects(cnt,hull)
for i in range(defects.shape[0]):
    s,e,f,d = defects[i,0]
    start = tuple(cnt[s][0])
    end = tuple(cnt[e][0])
    far = tuple(cnt[f][0])
cv2.line(img,start,end,[0,255,0],2)
cv2.circle(img,far,5,[0,0,255],-1)
cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

According to opencv-pyhthon manual `cv2.convexityDefects()` returns four values which are [ start point, end point, farthest point, approximate
distance to farthest point ].

I do not understand how the five lines of for loop is working?

Comment: What don't you understand ? The syntax of `s,e,f,d = defects[i,0]` ?

Comment: What is meant by defects.shape[0], The syntax of s,e,f,d = defects[i,0] and what is meant by tuple(cnt[s][0])?

Answer (score 1):

Look to the [official docs](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#convexitydefects).
s, e, f are just indexes of the points on the contour. d is distance  the distance between the farthest contour point and the hull.